# Conditional Poisson with Same Variable

Tags: self-study

Let $T$ be the amount of time needed for two cars to show up at a stop sign. The average rate of car showing up is 1 car per 10 minutes. Given that $T>5$, what is the probability of $T>15$?

I'm trying to do this problem with conditional probability but am tempted to think that I should just calculate for $P(T>15)$ but then that doesn't take into account of the conditional probability. If I do Baye's rule: $P(T>15,T>5)/ P(T>5)$ then the $P(T>15,T>5)$ doesn't make much sense either (Probability of T>15 and T>5). Does the top $P(T>15,T>5)$ collapse into $P(T>15)$? Or should I parse the timeline?

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $N$ that counts the number of cars is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda=0.1$, i.e. the number of events in any interval of length $t$ is a Poisson variable with mean $\lambda t$. Therefore, the random variable $T$, which is the time difference between the passages of two cars, follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, i.e. 
$$ f_\lambda(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda  x} \hspace{1mm} for \hspace{1mm} x>0. $$

As explained in the dedicated Wikipedia page, the variable $T$ has the memoryless property, meaning that 'the existence of one point existing in a finite interval does not affect the probability (distribution) of other points existing'. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution.

Consequently, $$ P(T>15|T>5)=P(T>10) = \int_{10}^{+\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda  x} dx =
e^{-10 \lambda}=e^{-1}$$